# C# Grid view error : Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. when updating a SQL Server table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, deployment

I want to update the employee details on grid row updating event but I am getting the following error:"System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: index "

Code aspx:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Visible="False">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID, TagName" ShowFooter="True" EmptyDataText="No Perticular Record Found" AllowPaging="True" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnPageIndexChanging="Grid1_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
      <Columns>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" ReadOnly="True" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="TagName" HeaderText="TagName" SortExpression="TagName"  ReadOnly="True"/>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Position" HeaderText="Position" SortExpression="Position" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Office" HeaderText="Office" SortExpression="Office" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="Salary"  HeaderText="Salary" SortExpression="Salary" />
    
          <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link"  ItemStyle-CssClass="editClass"  ShowEditButton="True" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>       
</asp:Panel>
```

C# code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

    int ID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
    string TagName = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text;
    string position = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Controls[0]).Text;
    string office = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Controls[0]).Text;
    string salary = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Controls[0]).Text;

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CS);
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update  Employee  set Position='" + position + "', Office='" + office + "',Salary=" + salary+" where ID="+ ID +" TagName='"+ TagName + "'" , conn);

    int t = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (t > 0)
    {
        Response.Write("<script> alert('Data has Updated')</script>");
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        Page_Load();
    }
}
```

Help me please. Thanks in advance for your time. ;)

Comment: What is the value of `e.RowIndex`?? Have you stepped through your code? The exception means you are exceeding the boundary of your collection.

Comment: Are you getting error when app starts?  Add test for RowIndex >= 0.  When the gridview is constructed you may be getting an exception.  Rowindex = -1 until the columns are added.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Which specific line throws the exception?

Comment: The following line is throws the error : string TagName = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text;